# Windows 7 can work with GPT and MBR disks?

Tags: windows-7, uefi, mbr, gpt

I have a problem that is driving me crazy.

I have installed a 64-bit Windows 7 on a 3TB disk (obviously with GPT partition), I have another 3TB disk also with GPT partition, and two other 1TB disks with MBR partition.

Everything worked fine for 2 months, but then I did not recognize the second 3TB disc. The Windows Disk Administrator asked me to initialize it, and when I chose the GPT partition it would boot it to 128MB.

The bios (UEFI) did not detect me this second disc of 3TB.

Thanks to GParted of Linux, I was able to create the GPT partition again and format NTFS, and the operating system saw it again.

The problem is that when I reconnect the 1TB disks, I do not recognize them, and again unconfigure the 3TB data disk.

Is it a Windows 7 problem? Is it a configuration problem for the UEFI bios, which is configured as UEFI Only ?.

Any help will be welcome.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Yes; Windows 7 supports GPT and MBR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is "Is it a Windows 7 problem?" I will say NO. Windows 7  supports both MBR and GPT. Reading your question again "Everything worked fine for 2 months" I think it is a hardware problem. Windows 7 does not forget to support MBR or GPT after two months... :-)